# Need to change IP addresses on 35 servers remotely

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, ip-address, netsh

We are going through a network redesign and I have 35 Windows 2003/2008 servers at a remote location that I need to change the IP address, gateway and DNS informaiton for.

Ideally I would like to be able to preform this from a command line on my local system (Windows 7) remotly, so I can script out the process to update all systems quickly.

I have looked into netsh, but I'm having problems getting it to change the address remotly. For testing I'm tring to run the following comand which should return the current network config on the remote machine:

```
netsh -r \\server interface ip show config
```

However, the following error is returned:

> WARNING: Could not obtain host information from machine: [\server]. Some commands may not be available.
>
> The parameter is incorrect.
>
> The following command was not found: interface ip show config.

If I login to the server over RDP I am able to run the command netsh interface ip show config, and I receive the expected results.

This would seem to indicate, as the error is saying, that not all commands and funtions are available from a remote machine as might be available from a local session.

Is there any other method that I can use to accomplish the task of changing the IP address information for these servers remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would PSTOOLS psexec suffice for this?  You can open up a command prompt on a remote machine from your local desktop with:

psexec \\servername -u username -p password cmd

Comment: I have tested this solution and it appears to work. The only downside is thre is a bit of a delay becuase PSEXEC loses it's connection to the remote system becuase the IP address is changed. This is not a real problem, it just means that the execution for each command takes about 20 seconds instead of the 1 or 2 scond normal time.

Comment: For others, I'm using NETSH in the "cmd" section of the psexec process to preform the IP address change. I then start two addtional psexec tasks to set the DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [xcmd tool](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/remoteinvocation/article.php/c5433/) to logon first on the remote machine then execute your netsh command as if you were doing it locally.

```
xCmd.exe \\remoteserver /user:Administrator /pwd:* netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static ipaddr subnetmask gateway metric
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not mind to change approach and can use Python, I believe [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/tutorial.html) could be a nice solution for your needs, although I never actually tested it on Windows machines.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can write a batch (.bat file), upload it, login via RDP and run it?